# calculate cosine similarity in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cosine-similarity, recommendation-engine

I have a file (tags.csv) that contains UserId, MovieId,tags.I  want to use a domain-based method to calculate the cosine similarity between tags. I want to show the relevant tags for comedy only and measure similarity for each tag relevant to the comedy tag.

dataset

[image: example of data in file]

My code is:

```
val rows = sc.textFile("/usr/local/comedy")
val vecData = rows.map(line => Vectors.dense(line.split(", ").map(_.toDouble)))
val mat = new RowMatrix(vecData)
val exact = mat.columnSimilarities()
val approx = mat.columnSimilarities(0.07)
val exactEntries = exact.entries.map { case MatrixEntry(i, j, u) => ((i, j), u) }
val approxEntries = approx.entries.map { case MatrixEntry(i, j, v) => ((i, j), v) }
val MAE = exactEntries.leftOuterJoin(approxEntries).values.map {
  case (u, Some(v)) =>
    math.abs(u - v)
  case (u, None) =>
    math.abs(u)
}.mean()
```

but this error appear:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[1,898,"black comedy"]"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. There are non-numeric characters in the `String` you are trying to translate into a number.

Comment: please, can you tell me how to overcome this although I want to use tags .

Comment: You need to parse the input such that only the number parts are sent to `.toDouble`. You haven't posted any examples of the file data so we can't make any suggestions but you can figure it out.

Comment: I update question with sample of file data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is full of pertinent info.

```
NumberFormatException: For input string: "[1,898,"black comedy"]"
```

It looks like the input `String` isn't being split into separate column data. So `.split(", ")` isn't doing its job and it's easy to see why, there are no comma-space sequences to split on.

We could take out the space and split on just the comma but that would still leave a non-digit `[` in the 1st column data and the 3rd column data has no digit characters at all.

There are a few different ways to attack this. I'd be tempted to use a regex parser.

```
val twoNums = "(\\d+),(\\d+),".r.unanchored
val vecData = rows.collect{ case twoNums(a, b) =>
                Vectors.dense(Array(a.toDouble, b.toDouble))
              }
```

Comment: thanks so much. please can you help me to calculate cosine similarity for tags as table :tag l similarity l funny l 0.0523 , black comedy l 0.477 , dark comedy l 0.471, humor l 0.326.